# Error while building Tor on arm system

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, arm, tor

I'm trying to build Tor from source on my NAS (Synology DS213j).

./configure fails with this error (snippet of config.log):

```
configure:4097: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4119: gcc -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16  -I${top_srcdir}/src/common -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 conftest.c  >&5
conftest.c:1: sorry, unimplemented: -mfloat-abi=hard and VFP
```

If I try to build without `-mfloat-abi=hard` then I get

```
configure:4097: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4119: gcc   -I${top_srcdir}/src/common  conftest.c  >&5
/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.2.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: ERROR: /lib/libc.so.6 uses VFP register arguments, a.out does not
/opt/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.2.3/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: failed to merge target specific data of file /lib/libc.so.6
```

My guess is that vfp is needed to compile, but my compiler chokes on it for some reason, although the processor (Marvell Armada 370) should support it.

So how do I get VFP into my compiler?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where did your compiler come from?
Your (7 years old) toolchain is probably a soft-float one, meaning you cannot make use of the VFP even though it exists. If that is the correct toolchain for your device, then it most likely uses a softfloat libc to be compatible with older devices.

Comment: @unixsmurf i got it from the ipkg repository that came with [this](https://github.com/trepmag/ds213j-optware-bootstrap) bootstrap.
If you (or someone) could point me to a more up to date toolchain, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yeah that is an old softfloat thing, to be compatible between lots and lots of different devices. Your best bet might be something like http://www.rooot.net/en/geek-stuff/synology/39-chroot-debian-synology-debootstrap.html - although if doing a new one now, might want to use the soon-to-be-released "jessie" rather then "wheezy".

Comment: thanks for the link! that's even better suited for my needs than the bootstrap I used and I was able to get Tor running without any problems. Thank you!

Comment: @unixsmurf if you want to make your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: thanks. Currently debating with myself as to whether the answer would be on-topic. I'll revisit tonight. Glad to hear it worked out for you.

Comment: @unixsmurf from my point of view, it does solve my question about getting a VFP-capable compiler, even if it's not the "cleanest" solution.